# Rails Devise check if User has not Logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to check if the user session is not active

```
<% if user_signed_in?! %>
        <div class="homeActions">
          <%= link_to "Become a Host", new_host_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success" %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: `<% unless current_user %>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
<% if !user_signed_in? %>
```

or

```
<% if not user_signed_in? %>
```

or

```
<% unless user_signed_in? %>
```

`!` and `not` negate the preceding boolean expression, while `unless` is the exact opposite of `if`.